# AngularJS, radio buttons with getters and setters

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to have radio buttons controlling boolean properties of external objects through getters and setters.

In the following example, there are multiple `Person`, but only one can be `happy`. One of them is already happy. I want to control which one is happy through radio buttons.

Therefore, I created a template with a radio input, but I can't bind it to `person.happy`, as I don't have access to this property (suppose `Person` is a third-party library).

In order to bind something to the input, I created a dumb controller, to provide a default value (the `Person` value), and propagate changes to the real variable (in short, call the setter). I can't seem to get things right.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

// Person constructor ; happy is a private member
function Person(name, isHappy) {
  var happy = isHappy;
  this.name = name;
  this.getHappy = function() { return happy; }
  this.setHappy = function(value) { happy = value; }
}

// Inject a person list in the scope
app.controller('PeopleCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.people = [
    new Person('Alice', true),
    new Person('Bob', false),
    new Person('Carol', false)
  ];
});

// Template to display one person + happiness controller
var humanTemplate = [
  '<div><label>',
  '<input type="radio" name="group" ng-model="me.happy" ng-change="me.toggle()" value="{{ !me.happy }}">',
  '<span>{{ person.name }} is {{ me.happy ? "happy" : "sad" }}</span>',
  '</label></div>'
].join('');

// Directive to display one person
app.directive('human', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: humanTemplate,
    scope: {
      person: '='
    },
    controllerAs: 'me',
    controller: function($scope) {
      var me = this;
      me.happy = $scope.person.getHappy();
      me.toggle = function() {
        console.log(me.happy);
        $scope.person.setHappy(me.happy);
      };
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="PeopleCtrl">
  <human ng-repeat="p in people" person="p"></human>
</div>
```

I would have thought `ngChange` would be tied to the `checked` state on radio and checkboxes (would have been somehow logical), but there are symptoms telling me otherwise:

- `ngChange` is not fired for the previously checked radio
- `ngChange` is not fired more than once (I got it to fire twice when messing with the input `value` attribute)

I may be mistaken since I am a beginner, but it looks like `ngChange` is not what I want.

What do you think would be a good solution for this problem?
Do I need to write a parent controller to manage manually the deactivation of some items when the other get activated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think (at least what I see from demo) you use radio buttons with different purpose.

Radio buttons works in groups where each button has shared `ng-model`. In your case `human` directive has own scope and therefore each radio button has own model a.e. stand-alone, that breaks  radio buttons concept and usage.

Change to  classic checkbox `type="checkbox"` and everything will work properly

<kbd>[Demo Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/tBzmx7dVyUmrHPHDmrZA?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: I really want them to behave like radio buttons, with only one being `checked` at any given time, that's why they share their `name` attribute. If I understand well, I cannot have this uniqueness without implementing the `toggle()` method in a parent controller like `PeopleCtrl`, regardless of whether I use radio or checkbox?

Comment: @GnxR `I really want them to behave like radio buttons, with only one being checked at any given time, that's why they share their name attribute.` all of them should have same `ng-model`. So u can create it in controller and pass to directives